# Layout custom listview in android

Tags: android

How Can I layout my custom listview exactly below?
thanks

[image]

Comment: show your effort what you have tried ??

Comment: If you need someone to write code, hire a developer.

Comment: At Stack Overflow, we don't write your code for you. Show your research; [edit] your question to contain a [mcve]. Learn [off-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just giving you understanding create listview layout design like this

Best of Luck.

[image]

Comment: 1+ for your effort...